# dynamically update webform submitted fields using rules

Tags: dynamic, drupal-7, field, drupal-webform, drupal-rules

I am newbie to drupal and seeking help in creating rules for dynamically updating webform fields affter submission. I created a form using webform for sponsors and redirected after save to ubercart product for payment. Now I have to create a rule according to the product(Platinum Sponsorship/Gold Sponsorship) and update the sponsorship field on order completion. I created the rule but stucked while setting value of the field (rule action) sponsor to (platinum/gold) as webform fields are not appearing in data selector.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need the [Webform Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules).

> This module adds rules integration on webforms.
>
> Did you ever want to react on webform submission using rules but
>   couldn't find the proper event? Webform Rules makes it possible to
>   catch webform submissions by rules and do whatever you'd like to do
>   with it (meaning: do whatever rules let you do with it).

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, make sure you have the [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module enabled (as suggested already in the prior answer).

But, you may also want to have a look at feature request "[Expose submission data to rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2020149)". Here is a summary of it:

> Right now, submission data is not exposed to rules except by way of token replacement or custom php actions. This patch exposes submission data in a "first-class" way.

Issue status is "Needs review" ... but not an "easy" issue either.

After that issue is resolved, you'll be able to do what you're asking for. So right now this is as good as it gets.